# Google analytics tracker not started in ionic 2 app

Tags: html, angular, google-analytics, ionic2

Im using google analytics in my app. I want to start tracking on platform ready. But the code consoled in to catch function. My code is

```js
GoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-xxxxxxxx-1'); //replaced id
.then(function() {
  console.log('Google analytics is ready now');

}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e);
});
```

My output is **Error starting GoogleAnalytics Tracker not started**. How to solve this? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the latest ionic the problem was in an old ionic native version where the parameters had a problem, have a look here:
https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/291

I've got the same issue, after updating all plugins inside the platform.json the tracking is working without any problems.

Comment: Thank you but it was solved. It is not beacuace of native plugins problem. I didn't add client id properly with the plugin. There is need to add reversed client id like com.googleuseraccounts.apps xxxxxxxx. while installing the plugin.Anyway your ans is helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure its in Platform ready, And it will only work on a device.

```
import { GoogleAnalytics } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public plt: Platform) {

    this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {
    GoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('YOUR_TRACKER_ID')
       .then(() => {
         console.log('Google analytics is ready now');
         // Tracker is ready
         // You can now track pages or set additional information such as AppVersion or UserId
       })
       .catch(e => console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e));
    });
}
```

Comment: @SuryaTeja I just tried it and it does work.. Are you getting any errors / logs ?  Are you sure you are using Google analytics mobile account ?

Comment: Ya I'm using Google mobile account...I don't know why the catch function consoled every time..There are no errors...Only the error message is showed..Tracker not started..

Comment: @SuryaTeja The "then" creates a promise and waits for the tracker. I start it from the  app.componant page

Comment: Device ready is fired after few milli seconds..Is there any problem because of it?

Comment: also tried in setTimeout() function...But there is no success

Answer (score 0):

Is a problem related with google-play-services incompatibilities. For fix it you have to make sure that all the PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION are the same, in my case for google-maps, googleplus  and the rest I used 15.0.2, but for analytics I have to use 15.0.2 (because there are not a 15.0.1 in maven repo).

SO go to your config.xml and add/change your analytics plugin tag to

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics">
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="15.0.2" />
    </plugin>
```

and make sure that all the other plugins have some 15.* version. (if you are using another one just make sure that all play service use the same version)

Then if you already added a platform, go to platforms/android/project.properties and the same, just make sure that all play-services libraries are the same version. for example I have:

```
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2
cordova.system.library.13=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
```

...

Hope that this work for you, work for me after a lot of research.